# Express timeout always occurs after 1 minute

Tags: node.js, express, cloud-foundry

I have an express server that hits a 1 minute timeout after publishing it to Cloud Foundry. Locally I can set any timeout that I want. It is probably a problem with Pivotal Cloud Foundry, but I am not sure what setting could be breaking things. Here is what I have tried in code:

https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/http.html#http_server_settimeout_msecs_callback

https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/http.html#http_server_timeout

https://github.com/expressjs/timeout

https://github.com/expressjs/express/issues/2174

Then just for kicks I put all of them into my code, and It still timed out after 1 minute. This is the raw response I get:

```
HTTP/1.1 504 GATEWAY_TIMEOUT
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive
```

I think there is some linux server configuration that maybe I have to set. Is there anything on node that would hard limit how long a connection can last? What would make it send that response? There is nothing in my code that would send a `504 GATEWAY_TIMEOUT`. Locally when I set a 1 minute time out I don't even get that response. I get:

```
Empty reply from server
```

That is normal. Any suggestions are appreciated.

--------------------UPDATE--------------------

The GoRouter that Francisco Mateo spoke of is indeed the issue, but according to Pivotal support:

> To change the timeout on the go router, you would have to modify the BOSH manifest of the go router. In a full Pivotal Cloud Foundry environment, this is a trivial change. However, we do not allow such changes to be made on Pivotal Web Services since they would affect more than a single customer.

It is apparently impossible to over ride it, but I can keep the connection alive if I send data every now and then. So if I send an empty space every 10 seconds then I can keep the connection alive forever. That is ugly though. The response will have a bunch of empty spaces and then the data will be shown.

Next question:

Is there any way to send a ping with no data?

I have tried sending an empty string but the Go Router sees that as sending nothing. Maybe an empty character?

Comment: Can you include `cf logs` output when you send the request?  Also, do short/quick requests work OK?  If you're hitting the 60s timeout Francisco mentioned, quick requests like for static files would be OK and only long requests would fail.  Lastly, is your app stable?  or do you see it crashing & restarting?  Maybe look at `cf events` to confirm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Node or your Express application. This is due do the [`gorouter`](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/gorouter) that Cloud Foundry uses which sets a timeout of 60 seconds.

See:

- https://github.com/cloudfoundry/gorouter/issues/100
- https://cf-docs.jp-east-https://cf-docs.jp-east-1.paas.cloud.global.fujitsu.com/en/manual/faq/faq/topics/c-faq-14.html

There may be a way to override it: https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/services/route-services.html#timeouts

Comment: I'm not so sure this is right.  While the property you mention does default to 60s, in most cases this gets set to 900s by the bosh release, usually to allow for large uploads.

Comment: He is correct, and you are correct. The connection will stay alive for 900s, but only so long as there is data going across the connection. In my case there is no data going across the connection, but it needs to stay awake for that long.